# If $f \colon[ a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and Riemann-integrable, is $F(x):=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ always differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, riemann-integration

Is the following statement true or false?

> Let $ f \colon [ a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded and Riemann-integrable function. Define
>   $$ [a,b]\ni x\mapsto F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt.$$
>   Then the  function $ F$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$.

My attempt: I thinks this statement is false. As a counterexample I am thinking of

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} |x|, & x \in [-1,1], \\ 1,&  \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: In your example $F$ is differentiable on $(-1,1)$ and $F'(x)=|x|$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy   sir   $ |x|$  is not differentiable  at origin

Comment: That just means that $F'$ is not differentiable.

Comment: What is true is that $F$ is differentiable [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) on $(a,b)$ with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't work because $f$ is continuous. Take $f(x)=-1$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $0 < x \leq 1$. If you compute $F$ you will see that the right hand derivative of $F$ at $0$ is $+1$ and the left hand derivative is $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your counterexample won't work because the derivative of $F$ is just $f$ on $(a,b)$.

Take $f\colon[0,2]\to \Bbb R$ as the step function with $f(x)=0$ for $x<1$ and $f(x)=1$ for $1\le x\le 2$. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable, and $F$ is a piecewise linear function which is $0$ from $0$ to $1$, and then $F(x)=x-1$ for $1\le x\le 2$. In particular $F$ is not differentiable at $1$.

Comment: $f$ need not be continuous at $c$ for $F'(c)$ to exist. For example, define $f(t)=\sin(1/t), t > 0,$ $f(t)=0$ elsewhere. Then $F'(0)=0.$

Comment: You’re definitely right; otherwise continuous would be interchangeable with having an anti-derivative which is not true. So only the one implication